# C# WSDL soap API - Immediate Error 401 on production server only? Windows Server 2008

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl, windows-server-2008, basic-authentication

Upon calling a 3rd party SOAP endpoint i'm getting a 401 Unauthorised error - This is from my production server only. Works fine on every other machine I've tested on.

Production is running on Windows server 2008

I'm using the wsdl url to setup the request. I've noticed it seems to throw back the 401 so fast, that it doesn't seem to even be sending it to the remote machine. Is there perhaps some machine specific config that could be causing this?

I'm unsure of how to debug the situation as i can't replicate it on my local machine

There is no code i can think of that might help with this issue, since it is literally a single call of a SOAP wsdl

Answer (score 0):

```
                this.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

Placed the above manually inside the initialization of the class. From scouring the internet it seems occasionally windows server will use weird credentials and fail to bypass its own checks resulting in a 401 immediately.

Forcing useDefaultCredentials fixes this issue.